# Prove a Poincare-Like Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Here is the question. Given any $\alpha>0$ and $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, $\Omega=B(0,1)$ in $n$ dimensions. Then we have
$$\int_\Omega |u|^2 dx\leq C(\alpha)\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx $$
provided that the set $M:=\{x\in \Omega, \,\, u(x)=0\}$ has measure more then $\alpha$, i.e., $|M|>\alpha$.

I have a solution  but my solution requires that $\alpha$ large enough, i.e., I need $\alpha\geq c>0$ for some constant $c$ and I don't know how to remove this additional assumption...

Anyhow, here is my approach:
Let $$u_\Omega:= \frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_\Omega u dx$$
i.e., the mean value of $u$ in $\Omega$.

Then I have
$$|u_\Omega|^2 =   \frac{1}{|\Omega|^2} \left(\int_{\Omega\setminus M} u dx\right)^2\leq \frac{|\Omega\setminus M|}{|\Omega|^2} \left(\int_{\Omega\setminus M} u^2 dx\right)\leq \frac{|\Omega\setminus M|}{|\Omega|^2} \left(\int_{\Omega} u^2 dx\right)$$
The Last inequality is by Holder.

Thus I have
$$\int_\Omega |u|^2 dx\leq 2\int_\Omega |u-u_\Omega|^2dx + 2\int_\Omega |u_\Omega|^2dx \leq 2\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx + 2\frac{|\Omega\setminus M|}{|\Omega|} \left(\int_{\Omega} u^2 dx\right)$$
and hence I need to make 
$$2\frac{|\Omega\setminus M|}{|\Omega|} <1$$
which require $\alpha$ large enough... But question state that this is true for any $\alpha>0$. Where am I missing?

Edit: The below answer is really nice. But here let me point out a more generally Poincare inequality which I learned recently. Actually the Poincare inequality hold for any $E\subset \Omega$ such that $|E|>0$, then
$$ \int_\Omega |u-u_E|^2 dx\leq C\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx  $$
Hence we could take $E$ to be the $0$ set of $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ vanishes on a set of measure $\alpha$, then 
$$
\int_\Omega u^2\le C(\alpha) \int_\Omega (u-u_\Omega)^2
$$
 because $u_\Omega$ cannot be much larger than $\int u^2$. Indeed,
$$
\int_\Omega u^2\ge \int_\Omega (u-u_\Omega)^2 \ge \int_{\{u=0\}} (u-u_\Omega)^2
=\alpha (u_\Omega)^2
$$
hence
$$
\int_\Omega u^2 \le 2 (u_\Omega)^2+ 2 \int_\Omega (u-u_\Omega)^2    \le ( 2\alpha^{-1}+2)\int_\Omega (u-u_\Omega)^2
$$

Comment: How do you get $\int_\Omega u^2\geq \int_\Omega (u-u_\Omega)^2$ in second equation?

Comment: Just expand the square and simplify. This is also a known fact: subtracting the mean reduces root mean square.

Comment: The part "$\int_\Omega u^2\geq$" in the second line is irrelevant?

Comment: The "because" part of the argument is quite confusing.